# Redirect file write from external programm to memorystream and vice versa

Tags: c#

I use some external programs to edit files. I do this with System.Diagnostics.Process. These programs read the files from the hard disk, edit them and write them back.

But this is too slow due to the amount of files.
Is it now possible to transfer files to and receive them from an external program via a MemoryStream?

I thought about a RamDisk but wanted another solution because this doesn't work reliable enough. (Program technique creation of a RamDisk)

For one of the used programs (GhostScript, GhostScript. NET) there is the possibility to load the output directly in a memory stream. But not for e. g. cpdf.

Thank you for help.

Comment: Depends on the program. If they can handle stdin/stdout instead of files, you could use those. If you have to pass them a filename, you're out of luck.

Comment: Something like a ramdisk doesn't help *at all*.  You still pay for having to copy the files from the disk.  And you make it worse by having two copies of the file in memory, one in the file system cache and one in the ramdisk.  Making it less efficient.  No magic cure, you'll have to go shopping for more RAM and a nice SSD.  And above all, not wait for it to finish the job.

Comment: I have much RAM and a SSD. But faster is better :-D